# Using-statement with async call | Cancel operation?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, dispose, using-statement

I'm facing a general question where I can't find a good example to try-it-for-myself. Google isn't a help neither.

**Imagine a structure like this:**

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(sender, receiver);
using(SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
{
    client.Host ...
    client.Port ...

    mail.subject ...
    mail.body ...

    client.SendAsync(mail);
}
```

What if the server is slow and takes a while to accept the mail. Is it possible that the `SmtpClient` is disposed before the operation is done? Will it be canceled or broken in any way?

Is there a general answer for this? The servers in here are too fast, don't know how to do a try-out.

---

*If thinking about canceling a `BackgroundWorker` it's always finishing the current operation. Could be the same here, or maybe not...*

Comment: Yes, this code ***will*** dispose of the `client` before the email is sent. This is probably bad.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the newer `SendMailAsync` method that returns a `Task`, and await that task:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(sender, receiver);
using(SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
{
    client.Host ...
    client.Port ...

    mail.subject ...
    mail.body ...

    await client.SendMailAsync(mail);
}
```

This will ensure that the client isn't disposed before `SendMailAsync` completes.

(of course, this means your method now has to be async as well)

Comment: According your last sentence, `await` will block my thread, right?

Comment: @C4u no, `await` will *release* the thread, wait for the async operation to complete, then resume execution.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan Ah wow. Then I've got everything I was looking for. Big thanks to both of you :).